# The chart doesn't show for data from $http in Highchart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I get the chart when I hard code the data. But when I get the data from a server I don't see the chart. I saw many questions on this but they didn't help me. I change the data object with the scope variable but I still don't get the data
This is what I've done:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
        // Directive for generic chart, pass in chart options

        .directive('hcPieChart', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<div></div>',
                scope: {
                    title: '@',
                    data: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    Highcharts.chart(element[0], {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'pie'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: scope.title
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            pie: {
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            data: scope.data
                        }]
                    });
                }
            };
        })
        .controller('myController', function ($scope,$http) {


           $scope.GType = function(){    
            console.log("GType");
            $http.get('http://192.168.1.100:5000/getPDAServiceAssignStatus')
            .then(function (response) {

            $scope.pieData = []; 
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response)+" Res");
                    for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++){
                        $scope.pieData.push({
                            name: response.data[i].name,
                             y:response.data[i].y

                        });
                    }
                    console.log($scope.pieData);

                });
            }
            $scope.GType();
            //  $scope.pieData = [{
            //         name: "Microsoft Internet Explorer",
            //         y: 56.33
            //     }, {
            //         name: "Chrome",
            //         y: 24.03,
            //         sliced: true,
            //         selected: true
            //     }, {
            //         name: "Firefox",
            //         y: 10.38
            //     }, {
            //         name: "Safari",
            //         y: 4.77
            //     }, {
            //         name: "Opera",
            //         y: 0.91
            //     }, {
            //         name: "Proprietary or Undetectable",
            //         y: 0.2
            // }]
        });
```

Comment: try chart.redraw() after adding data

Comment: @AsadSarwar. where should i do that?

Comment: console.log($scope.pieData) try $scope.redraw()

Comment: @AsadSarwar. i get `redraw()` is not a function.

Comment: To dynamically set new data for a series use [`Series.setData`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData) or [`Series.update`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update).

Comment: @KacperMadej. should i add a `$watch` and update? Can you please add an answer on how to do this

Comment: [Here's more info about using Highcharts with AngularJS.](http://www.highcharts.com/blog/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js) There is an already created directive, so you do not need to create your own - it supports dynamic changes through `$watch` - [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng). If you will still have problems please post a demo in Plunker (it supports multiple files) on in JSFiddle (it's possible to use AngularJS there too).